# Does the mass of water molecule increase when its just converted from ice to water?

Tags: relativity

When we heat some object and its temperature raised then the K.E of molecules increased it means increase in velocity and according to $m=\frac{m०}{{(1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}})^{1/2}}$ mass is increased in very small amount.but when latent heat is gained by ice at $0°\text{C}$ and its converted to water at $0°\text{C}$, I think its K.E. is not increased, so I'm confused where has this energy of latent heat gone after separating molecules

Comment: Welcome on Physics SE :) Please extend and elaborate your question a bit. Why do you expect an increase in the mass of the molecule? What effects would you be looking for?

Comment: Hi Sagar. Can you give us a bit of background? For example why do you think the mass might increase?

Comment: Hi Sagar, can I guess that you think that mass increases,  because ice floats in water?

Answer (score 1):

In the past, we might have said that any increase in molecular mass due to velocity increase would only be significant at speeds near that of light, but that is not how we view mass today at those velocities. No amount of heat we could put into water would ever result in molecular velocities anywhere near the speed of light.

The latent heat energy is used up in the phase change from ice to water, that is breaking the bonds that keep the water as crystal ice, and when liquid water is produced, it is (usually briefly) at the same temperature as the ice.

So that's where the latent heat energy goes, into breaking chemical bonds, with  none left over to increase the k.e. of the water molecules